# Figma design to react component

Tags: reactjs, figma, figma-api

I have a list of React component like Table, button, pagination, etc,.
Now I am in a need of creating Figma plugin that generate web page(react class component) from figma design using my React component which i already have.  is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

search for "Figma to React Component" plugin within the figma community tab. It may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Sync your Figma design to your Anima project. Step 2: Go to your project screen in the Anima web app and select the screen(s) you want to convert to React. Step 3: Make sure your prototype matches your design, then click the '<> Code' icon at the top of the window to enter Code Mode.